# Listing a Component under Application bootstrap property

Tags: yii2

I am working on a module extension and there is an official component named [yii2-jsUrlManager](https://github.com/dmirogin/yii2-js-urlmanager) which I am trying to configure.

The docs say that I need to add the component under the `components` and `bootstrap`

> 1. Add a component to your application configuration
>
>    ```
>    'jsUrlManager' => [
>        'class' => \dmirogin\js\urlmanager\JsUrlManager::class, 
>     ],
>    ```
> 2. Add component to bootstrap
>
>    ```
>    'bootstrap' => ['jsUrlManager'],
>    ```

which means that my config will look like the following

```
[
    'components'=>[

      //...other components

      'jsUrlManager' => [
           'class' => \dmirogin\js\urlmanager\JsUrlManager::class,
       ],

      //...other components
    ],
    'bootstrap'=>['jsUrlManager']
]
```

This is pretty straight forward but what if I am listing the component under the module like below

```
[
    'modules' => [
        'idows' => [
            'class' => 'path\to\Module',
            'components' => [
                'jsUrlManager' => [
                    'class' => \dmirogin\js\urlmanager\JsUrlManager::class,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'bootstrap' => [
        'jsUrlManager',
    ],
]
```

When I implement it like above it throws an Exception like below

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>
> Unknown bootstrapping component ID: jsUrlManager

So how do I list the component ID under the `bootstrap` property while it is attached under the `components` section of a module rather than the default `components`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'bootstrap' => ['jsUrlManager']` is a shortcut which may handle simple cases, but for any non-standard case (like yours) you should use Closure to bootstrap component:

```
'bootstrap' => [
    'jsUrlManager' => function ($app) {
        return $app->getModule('idows')->get('jsUrlManager');
    },
],
```